# standalone application in python

Tags: python

I wanted to know how can I make standalone application in python.
Basically what I am doing right now is I have a template.tex file and my script generate the pdf by giving some input values.
So I have to make exe file for windows and same for linux.
I can use cx_freeze for creating exe file.
But my problem is most of people do not contain latex on their computer.
SO how can I make latex get install when I first run my exe.
Basically how to make make file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could write a installer (using NSIS or something) that does two things :

- install LateX (or make sure there is an installation of latex available), potentially by calling another installer
- then install your python script (which can assume latex is now available)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a decent installer which can check for latex and if it's not there, install it. If you were feeling really brave you could use that to download Python as well which could avoid the requirement to use py2exe or freeze.

I've used the [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) before and it's relatively easy to get something working quickly on windows at least.

Given that you're developing on multiple platforms, [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/) might be of more use to you.